# How to draw a self-definition piecewise function using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, plot, piecewise

```
f = function(x) {
  y <- rep(0, length(x))
  y <- x[x >= 0 & x < 1]
  y <- 2 - x[x >= 1 & x < 2]
  return(y)
}
```

Here is one way I used to get plot of piecewise function `f`. How to use command `ifelse` to get a plot of f(x)?

Comment: Take a look at `?Vectorize`

Comment: It looks wrong to me : at lines 3 and 4 of your function, you just generate a new version of `y`. Don't you mean ` y <- y + ...`?

Comment: To answer your question: use two nested `ifelse`s.

Comment: If I understand, you can try: `y<-ifelse(x>=0 & x<1,x,ifelse(x>=1 & x<2,2-x,0))`.